# How do I set active go build tags for static analysis in VSCode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, build

VSCode uses a number of tools to do static code analysis and intellisense...

However, I haven't seen how to configure what build-tags should be enabled for those analysis?

e.g. I may have two files - one that is compiled `// +build debug` and its compliment compiled `// +build !debug` to enable some debug-only code and some production-time code or constants or so on...

but VSCode just flags all sorts of stuff as broken because it tries to analyze with both of these files present in the working namespace at once.

Surely there is a way to say `"editor build tag" : [ "debug" ]` or similar, so that the static analysis and linting tools aren't throwing bogus warnings / problem lists.

Answer (score 15):

The setting to add [build tags](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#gobuildtags) to vscode-go via the file `settings.json` is:

```
{
  ...
  "go.buildTags": "debug",
  ...
}
```

Comment: should this be added to the vscode's `settings.json` file?

Comment: @Dejavu yes this needs to be added to the `settings.json`

Comment: Multiple works as well: `"go.buildTags": "integration,unit",`